# Docker container Flask application crashes on Heroku but runs runs fine directly on docker

Tags: python, docker, flask, heroku, containers

I am trying to deploy a containerized Flask web application on Heroku, but it does not run and I get the below errors in Heroku's logs `heroku logs --tail --app containerized-test-app`:

```
2021-09-18T23:31:47.871670+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-09-18T23:31:55.365419+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `/bin/sh -c python3.9\ /opt/stonks_app/start.py`
2021-09-18T23:31:56.239496+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2021-09-18T23:31:56.449132+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-09-18T23:50:48.138595+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-09-18T23:50:55.304916+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `/bin/sh -c python3.9\ /opt/stonks_app/start.py`
2021-09-18T23:50:56.157266+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2021-09-18T23:50:56.218715+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-09-18T23:50:56.225279+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-09-18T23:51:03.727340+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `/bin/sh -c python3.9\ /opt/stonks_app/start.py`
2021-09-18T23:51:04.765823+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2021-09-18T23:51:04.818465+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-09-18T23:51:26.078144+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=containerized-test-app.herokuapp.com request_id=554a4918-2c4a-4f63-b06e-dc31e916d690 fwd="<ip-address>" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2021-09-18T23:51:58.341527+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=containerized-test-app.herokuapp.com request_id=194af19d-f7fa-4ea9-9165-3f3fbf64b559 fwd="<ip-address>" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2021-09-18T23:52:33.549024+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/keep-alive" host=containerized-test-app.herokuapp.com request_id=cc14783a-c2a5-4327-9d35-8453c26b542e fwd="<ip-address>" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
```

Everything required by the application is bundled into a single docker container built using `heroku container:push web --recursive --app containerized-test-app`. This container works perfectly fine on my local docker setup without any errors. Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:11.0-slim

RUN apt update -y
RUN apt install -y python3.9 python3-pip

RUN python3 -m pip install --no-cache --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

ADD ./stonks_app/requirements.txt /tmp/
RUN python3 -m pip install --no-cache -r /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN rm /tmp/requirements.txt

ADD ./stonks_app/start.py /opt/stonks_app/
ADD ./stonks_app/stonks_app/* /opt/stonks_app/stonks_app/

ENTRYPOINT python3.9 /opt/stonks_app/start.py
```

The source files copied have a pretty standard Flask folder structure too.

```
─── stonks_app
    ├── requirements.txt
    ├── start.py
    └── stonks_app
        ├── __init__.py
        └── stonks_app.py
```

In the files above, **init**.py is empty. I configured start.py to start CherryPy server on the port set up in environment variable PORT (if any) as first priority:

```
import argparse
import cherrypy
import os
from paste.translogger import TransLogger
from stonks_app.stonks_app import app


def start(socket_port):
    logged_app = TransLogger(app)
    cherrypy.tree.graft(logged_app, '/')
    cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0',
                            'server.socket_port': socket_port,
                            'log.screen': True,
                            'engine.autoreload_on': True,
                            # increase the socket timeout from default 10 seconds to 60
                            'server.socket_timeout': 60
                            })
    cherrypy.engine.start()
    cherrypy.engine.block()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=True)
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--port', default=80,
                        help='Port for the flask application',
                        type=int)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', args.port))
    start(port)
```

The flask application as of now is completely barebones with a single functional endpoint:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, current_app
from datetime import datetime

version = '0.1.0'

app = Flask('__name__')

# configure the flask web app
app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True
app.config['SETTINGS'] = {}


@app.route('/keep-alive')
def keep_alive():
    return datetime.utcnow().isoformat()[:19] + 'UTC'
```

The error from Heroku is not specific enough on what's wrong and with the local container running without a hitch I am not sure what to do here. Any help on what is causing the error or how I may get better error logs through Heroku is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use heroku cli to trace back the whole error, run this command on the heroku cli: ```heroku logs --tail```.

Comment: That is the first thing I did. The logs do not offer any insight into why the application crashes, just that it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see `app.run()` in your code. To run the flask server you have to add this line:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: I am not using flask's in-built server but rather running it behind CherryPy. start.py described in the question calls the flask application. Furthermore, I know the code works - I have tested it on a docker container running directly on my host machine. It is only when I try to deploy the container to Heroku that the application crashes.